# `cron` service and `at` command

Tags: cron, command, at

Help to understand: is there any relation between `cron` and `at` command.

Actually if I stop the `cron` services in SUSE by running following command:

```
/etc/init.d/cron stop
```

after above, if I run `at` command with `at` work?
example:

```
at -f /u01/script1.sh now
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the exact method of invocation can vary between platforms and `at` implementations.

On any platforms/configuration, `at` jobs could conceivably be run by periodic `cron` jobs or other scheduler. On OS X, for example, `at` jobs are run by `launchd` via `/usr/libexec/atrun` on an interval.  Similarly, on FreeBSD `/usr/libexec/atrun` is run every few minutes by cron.

On my Debian 7 system, I have an `atd` service running which performs independently of cron. Despite this, it stores at jobs in `/var/spool/cron/{atjobs,atspool}`.

Correspondingly, I have an `/etc/init.d/atd` to start the service at boot. I believe this use of `atd` is common on many Linux systems, which appears to include SUSE.  In that case, `at` and `cron` are unrelated and independent of each other.

You can confirm how your system works. Stop your cron service and run the following command:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/testfile' | at now + 1 minute
```

Within 1 minute, check if `/tmp/testfile` exists. If it does, `at` jobs are being run.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate daemon for both.  The `crond` daemon runs your `cron` jobs and the `atd` dameon runs the `at` jobs.

You can read the manual pages for both with `man at` and `man crond`.