# What is the difference between shutdown 18:00 and at 18:00 shutdown?

Tags: centos, shutdown, at

`at 18:00 shutdown now` and `shutdown 18:00` , are they starting the same service? Do they work the same way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`at 18:00 shutdown now` creates an "at" job, which is performed at the specified time by the `at` daemon or perhaps the `cron` daemon, depending on your system.

`shutdown 18:00` starts a process in your shell that waits until the specified time and then performs the shutdown. This command can be terminated if e.g. your shell session is terminated.

The net result in most cases will be the same: the system is shutdown at 18:00.

One difference is that if you use `at`, the job will be stored and if the system is shutdown by some other means before 18:00, upon booting again the job will still be waiting to be run; if the time is already passed, the shutdown will be performed immediately which could be quite unexpected.

Another difference is that `shutdown 18:00` will create a `/run/nologin` file 5 minutes before the scheduled time to prevent people logging in after that moment. Also broadcast messages will be sent to warn logged in users that the system is about to be shutdown.

You need to take account these differences to decide which to use.

Comment: "`shutdown 18:00` starts a process in your shell that waits".  What if you log out before then?

Comment: @RonJohn: Then it depends if you used `nohup` or `disown` or whatever, if logging out normally kills *running* background processes.  Different systems can have different defaults for that.  (I'm assuming that there really is a `sudo shutdown` process still running, rather it just signalling `init` to start a shutdown timer.  The latter might actually be what happens, but I haven't checked recently.  Oh, but @JdeBP has; see that answer)

Comment: Is it really possible to set up `at` so it works via `cron` instead of `atd`?

Comment: There's a diamond moderator who has not read [ask].  (-:  You will find that this question was asked four years ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/ .

Comment: _"Also broadcast messages will be sent to warn logged in users that the system is about to be shutdown."_ I'd say this is the most important difference in servers that have many users, I would highlight it more in this answer.

Answer (score 23):

## And now, the systemd answer.

If you have CentOS 7, you have a systemd operating system and the answer is different.

`at 18:00 shutdown now` still schedules via the `at` subsystem, but that `shutdown` command, as well as the one that you invoke directly with `shutdown 18:00`, is different.  It's actually systemd's `systemctl` program.  `systemctl` does things differently.

First of all, `systemctl` sends the scheduled shutdown request off to be processed by a dæmon, pretty much like in the `at` case.  This is a systemd dæmon, though, specifically `logind` (the `systemd-shutdownd` dæmon having been removed from systemd in May 2015, which change has since percolated through to later minor versions of CentOS 7), not the `at` subsystem.  `systemctl` speaks an internal protocol to a (system-wide) Desktop Bus broker which in turn communicates with `logind`.

So, like in the `at` case, there's no `shutdown` process sitting there counting down and spawning the `wall` messages.  So one can log out and this will not affect the schedule, and cancelling is not as simple as merely interrupting/killing the foreground process of the login session.  Just like with `at`.

There *are still* messages, unlike in the `at` case, but they are issued by `logind`.  Also unlike the `at` case, the scheduled job does not persist across system restarts, so an actual shutdown cancels a scheduled one.  There *is* a file in the filesystem, but it is under `/run/systemd/shutdown` which is non-persistent storage.

Further differences are that there can be only *one* scheduled shutdown at a time, whereas one can submit multiple `at` jobs, and Policy Kit will apply rules to `shutdown` run in non-login-session context as an `at` job that are different to the rules applied to `shutdown` run in login-session context.  The latter might be more permissive, allowing (say) an *unprivileged* user who is logged in to the active login session to shut down the system.

## Further reading

- [My answer to What is the difference between these commands for bringing down a Linux server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132)
- [Error when running `shutdown -h now`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378900/)