# is there any difference between /usr/bin/poweroff and /usr/bin/shutdown?

Tags: linux, shutdown, systemctl

I just realized that /usr/bin/poweroff and /usr/bin/shutdown are symbolic link to systemctl, but I don't know how systemctl is being run.

so is there any difference between /usr/bin/poweroff and /usr/bin/shutdown?

**EDIT:** when I call any of these two programs, systemctl is being executed but I don't know what command/parameter is passed to systemctl.

when I type `systemctl --help`there are two options that may come into play

- halt                Shut down and halt the system
- poweroff             Shut down and power-off the system

but something tells me that both poweroff and shutdown are the same in here (I'm guessing)

I'm running Archlinux

Answer (score 1):

In most systems, every "shutdown" command is just a *symlink* to a common program/script 
which **changes its behaviour** based on how (with which "name") is invoked.

So, `poweroff` does a kind of shutdown which powers off the machine (usually via ACPI APIs), too and it's equivalent to `shutdown -hP`, while `shutdown`
as a command is more *generic* and can do many thigs after "stopping" the OS, based on with which flags is called.

For example `shutdown -r` reboots the machine while `shutdown -h` just stops the OS (and the machine is still powered on, while not usable).

Comment: It's an oversimplification to say that `poweroff` is equivalent to `shutdown -hP`.  It's equivalent to that _in the van Smoorenburg toolset_, but _in the systemd toolset_ both the `-h` and `-P` options are the defaults anyway and it is equivalent to plain `shutdown now`.  The `now` is important, by the way.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465337/5132

Comment: @JdeBP I agree the `now` is important (as +mmm minutes, btw) but the OP was asking about differences, not syntax ;)

Comment: right, but as far as I can see both programs are a symlink to systemctl, I don't see how systemctl is being used. What makes it interesting is that those flags mention here have not use with systemctl

Comment: `now` is important because without it there _is_ a difference.  Pay close attention to the user manual of the systemd toolset.