# shutdown at specific date

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I know that you can schedule a shutdown for a specific time via `shutdown -h 21:45` and that you shouldn't use crontabs for such things because of their repetitive nature. How can I schedule a shutdown for a specific ***date*** like 31st of August at 20:00pm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent Ubuntu versions use systemd and when the conventional `atd` and associated `at` scheduler for one-off commands is either not installed or not running **a one-off command can be scheduled with [`systemd-run`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html)**  which is somewhat easier than manually generating a [`systemd timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

```
 systemd-run --on-calendar="2019-08-31 20:00:00 CET" /sbin/shutdown now
```

Comment: The irony is that starting an entire service to do this is _almost_ superfluous. systemd's shutdown mechanism itself supports arbitrary points in time.  Its command-line tool simply does not provide the ability to access this, because it is not up to par with the command line of the BSD `shutdown`.  As I wrote in another answer, you who want this could try persuading the systemd people to make their `shutdown` tool more capable, with syntax of decades' standing, rather than going around the houses with `systemd-run`.

Comment: I get Invalid calendar spec: 2019-08-31 20:00:00 CET

Answer (score 13):

The `at` command is for scheduling one off future executions.

e.g.

```
% at 8pm Aug 31
at> echo hello
at> <EOT>
job 161 at Sat Aug 31 20:00:00 2019
```

(the "<EOT>" was produced by pressing control-D)

```
% atq
161     Sat Aug 31 20:00:00 2019 a sweh
```

You can put your `shutdown` command here.

Comment: Yes! I had forgotten about `at` when I posted - `at` is definitely meant for this in general, although in a company the accepted method may be `at` or `cron`, depending on conventions related to configuration management/deployment.

Comment: It is not exactly equivalent, note.    https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465322/5132

Comment: `at` is also able to take commands from a pipe: `echo "echo yup > $(tty)" | at now`.

Answer (score 8):

While `at` is the obvious way to do this, I think it will survive shutdowns, so if the machine reboots before the scheduled shutdown, it might shutdown again at the scheduled time. Therefore, using bash and GNU date we can use a delayed shutdown.

`/sbin/shutdown +$((  ( $( date -d "30 may 2019 13:15" +%s ) - $( date +%s ) ) / 60 + 1 ))`

NB: This is only accurate to one minute. It works by converting the scheduled time, and now to seconds since the UNIX epoch, calculating the difference, converting to minutes, and then using this as the delay to shutdown. It won't work correctly if the scheduled time is in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You use a better `shutdown` command.

The van Smoorenburg, Upstart, and systemd `shutdown` commands do not allow a date specification.  But the BSD `shutdown` command takes a date value in its specification of when to shut down, in the form `yymmddhhmm`.  This has been the case ever since 4BSD, and remains so with FreeBSD and OpenBSD.  NetBSD extended it to `ccyymmddhhmm`.

Because the nosh toolset is also usable on the BSDs, I gave my `shutdown` command the same capability, extending it to `CCYYMMDDHHMM` per NetBSD.  And because the nosh toolset is also usable on Linux, that gives Linux a shutdown command that takes dates.

It of course works with the nosh `system-manager`.  It also works with some other systems.  It sends signals to process #1 to enact stuff and the same signals are understood by some other system managers, such as `systemd`, which can also be shut down using it.

You could use it, or a tool like it; or you could try to persuade the authors of other Linux `shutdown` programs to extend their tools to also be as capable as the BSD `shutdown`.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`shutdown`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/shutdown.xml).  nosh toolset manual pages.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`system-manager`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/system-manager.xml).  nosh toolset manual pages.  Softwares.
- [`shutdown`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?shutdown+8).  *System Manager's Manual*.  NetBSD Manual pages. 2011-11-04.
- [`shutdown`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shutdown&sektion=8).  *FreeBSD System Managers' Manual*.  2018-01-01.
- [`shutdown`](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/shutdown.8).  OpenBSD Manual pages.  2015-01-21.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465337/5132

Answer (score 1):

To run the job only this year:

```
0 20 31 8 * test $(/bin/date +\%Y) = "2019" && /sbin/shutdown now
```

To run the job every year:

```
0 20 31 8 * /sbin/shutdown now
```

Answer (score -4):

There may be an option to input the year to the `shutdown` command, but cron can be used to run commands only once at a specific point in time. For your example, try

```
0 0 31 8 ? 2019  shutdown
```

Beware: the above is not standard cron syntax.

Comment: 1. This doesn’t say 20:00 pm, it says midnight.  2. I have never seen a cronjob with SIX fields for the timing.  What cron implementation are you referencing?

Comment: There isn't a `year` field in the `crontab` schedule

Comment: I realized afterwards this syntax is not "standard cron", so I agree, it should not be taken at face value. OP seems to imply there is a performance penalty associated with using cron, so in my Answer, I sought to clarify - there isn't any inherently inefficient about cron's implementation that makes unsuitable for one-off task. Is this what you think as well?