# `& disown` and `setsid` not working with ssh! They launch an `(sd-pam)` process, which is not working

Tags: ssh, fedora, systemd, reboot, disown

I'm trying to reboot the server after a specified time.

If logged in on the server this can be achieved with a command like this:

```bsh
sleep 10 && reboot
```

To make this command stay alive (without tmux or screen), even if the shell terminates, I tried many different options, but `setsid` and `& disown` are the most suitable ones:

```bsh
setsid bash -c 'sleep 10 && reboot' &
```

... or:

```bsh
bash -c 'sleep 10 && reboot' & disown
```

This is working so far on the server, even if I close the shell where I called this command from. But since I want to restart the server through **ssh** and quit immediately after calling that command (without waiting for the specified `sleep` time period), I assumed to be able to achieve that with the adjusted commands from above, like so:

```bsh
ssh user@server -t "setsid bash -c 'sleep 10 && reboot' &"
```

... or:

```bsh
ssh user@server -t "bash -c 'sleep 10 && reboot' & disown"
```

But interestingly these commands launch a process with the name `(sd-pam)` which will exit after the specified `sleep` time period without doing anything. But if you execute the command often enough, you will find that it does it's job in about 10% of cases. I investigated that behavior and found out, that the `(sd-pam)` process is limited in many ways (e.g. not able to read and write to and from files - therefore I cannot log anything in case the reboot command is throwing an error).

All commands were executed with the `root` user on Fedora 32.

### Edit:

Thanks to @UlrichSchwarz I came across [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292946/2524925):

```bsh
echo 'sleep 30; reboot' | at now
```

And this also works well with `ssh`:

```bsh
ssh user@server -t "echo 'sleep 30; reboot' | at now"
```

What is `at` doing differently from `setsid` and `& disown`?

Comment: I think you're really looking for the [`at` daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)), if you can live with 1-minute resolution: `echo reboot | at now + 1 minutes`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz You're right, that's what I was looking for and yes, minute resolution is fine for me. Thanks a lot! (But the `at` command wasn't preinstalled.)

Comment: But maybe someone is able to explain why my previous commands didn't work.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465322/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements would be served by the shutdown command which is capable of scheduling its activity to a later date if required. For instance using the "-r" switch for reboot and "+1" for a delay of 1 minute. However, shutdown does require elevation with sudo.

```
sudo shutdown -r '+1'
```

you can also do this for immediate reboots too using "now" rather than "+1".

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```